# How to change the size of the module icon in Netbean

Tags: netbeans, resize, icons

So, i have the module icon like this :

[image: module icon]

I am wondering how to change the size looks bigger, since when our screen resolution get bigger, the module icon size looks small.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with programming , can you please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in SO

Comment: @NejiSoltani It is a valid question, and the OP correctly included the "resize" tag for "Issues relating to the resizing of controls, windows, forms or screens". SO has thousands of questions on usability issues with IDEs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't explicitly change the sizes of those module icons in NetBeans, but it can be done implicitly by increasing the size of the font used by the NetBeans IDE.

That font size is unrelated to the font size used for displaying your source code; instead it is used for rendering IDE text such as labels on tabs ("**Files**", "**Services**", etc.), menu entries and file names within panels such as the **Projects** tab. When the font size of a file name is changed, NetBeans also makes a corresponding increase or decrease to the size of the icon (e.g. the module icon) to its  immediate left.

To modify the font size used by NetBeans specify the **fontsize** parameter when starting NetBeans. For example, to get NetBeans to use 18 point font (not recommended!) on Windows 10 I made this call:

C:\NetBeans82_151\bin\netbeans64.exe **--fontsize 18**

The second screen shot below shows that using 18 point font also increased the size of the icons:

[image: DefaultFont]

[image: 18PointFont]

I deliberately used a significantly larger font to clarify the effect of the change in the screen shots, and the overall result was ugly. But for your purposes perhaps a smaller increase in font size will help you with the size of the icons.

Answer (score -1):

it can be helpful for others.
you can edit **netbeans.conf** then append the **--fontsize 24** to **netbeans_default_options**
normally should work ;)