# netbeans problem on showing text within nimnus look and feel

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, look-and-feel

When I set my Netbeans look and feel to nimbus and a small font seems great .

But when I set the font size to 14(or bigger than) some size of texts are OK but others will be made smaller than like size 10(though I set the font size to 14).

the covered areas with green mean that the font within them are set great.

the covered areas with red mean than the font within them are set incorrect (smaller than gotten value)

Gtk THEME:[image]

Nimbus Look And Feel : [image]

OS : Linux Manjaro

Jdk : open jdk 14

Environment : GNOME

Netbeans : Apache Netbeans 12

"It probably happens only on Linux and might be a java SE problem not a Netbeans problem"

Comment: Please update your question with the following information: [1] Your O/S. [2] Your versions of NetBeans and JDK, [3] A screen shot demonstrating the problem.

Comment: OK, I understand your concern, but I don't know of a solution. However, one thing you can easily try is to specify the font size used by the NetBeans IDE itself, to see if that helps. To do that, specify a value for the **--fontsize** parameter when starting NetBeans. [See this SO answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48071384/2985643).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is within the Java on linux as it has some problem with javafx media players in linux as well.

Also as I tested other look and feels the only problem is in the nimbus and I have to report it to Oracle.